# Django base translation file is not used?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a Django project and would like to use `i18n` to have support of diferent languages.
In my template I write:

```
{% load i18n l10n %}
<span>{% trans 'Sun' %}</span>
```

then I create required directories inside my `BASE_DIR`:

```
./locale/LC_MESSAGES/ar
./locale/LC_MESSAGES/ru
```

My settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ar', _('Arabic')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

Then I run `python manage.py makemessages -a`, the `.po` files are getting created. So far, so good..

Examining the `.po` files I see the folowing (among tons of other lines):

```
#: myproject/web/templates/reports/mycalendar.html:24
#: venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/dates.py:11
msgid "Sun"
msgstr ""
```

Hey, *do they want me to translate all messages from Django myself*??

Lets open a file `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`:

```
msgid "Sun"
msgstr "أحد"
```

So, the translation already exists for this word!

Running `python manage.py compilemessages` - this has no effect for this word, it became English.

I've tried to include native django's locale path `LOCALE_PATHS`:

```
from django.conf import locale as django_locale
DJANGO_LOCALE_PATH = abspath(dirname(django_locale.__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    DJANGO_LOCALE_PATH,
    join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

No way. Still the line presents in my `.po` file and still msgstr is empty. I tried to delete these lines from my `.po` file, but after `makemessages` they appear again.

Now **the question is**: Why the native .po file is ignored and how to make it used?

Django==1.8.12